# cannot start weblogic from netbeans after windows 7 BSOD

Tags: netbeans, weblogic

after a BSOD in Windows 7 something gets corrupted and NetBeans cannot start a local WebLogic 10 server it didn't have any problems with before.
there is also a peculiar message appearing in NetBeans notification, with message and stacktrace almost identical to those reported in a filed [NetBeans bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=270907):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname can't be null
at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:139)
at org.netbeans.modules.weblogic.common.api.WebLogicRuntime.ping(WebLogicRuntime.java:623)
at org.netbeans.modules.weblogic.common.api.WebLogicRuntime.ping(WebLogicRuntime.java:612)
at org.netbeans.modules.weblogic.common.api.WebLogicRuntime.isRunning(WebLogicRuntime.java:500)
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.weblogic9.optional.WLStartServer.isRunning(WLStartServer.java:124)
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerInstance$3.run(ServerInstance.java:902)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303) 
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)
```

I tried multiple restarts since then, multiple netbeans restarts, tried even both NetBeans 8.1 and 9 - when starting WebLogic, NetBeans just is stuck with "Starting ..." message and never stops. You actually have to forcefully close NetBeans to stop this.

Comment: ah and tomcat was starting alright through netbeans - so it was a weblogic issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at some point i tried to start weblogic outside NetBeans, and saw that it was failing to start, with a message approximately like this from [this Oracle forum thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1081036):

```
<Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000362> <Server failed. Reason: [Management:141268]Parsing Failure in config.xml on line 1, column 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.>
```

Well, indeed there is a directory inside WebLogic domain I was trying to start called "config", with a file "config.xml" there (and a config.loc - deleting it didn't make any difference) - so I tried to look into config.xml and WOW it was totally corrupted. So that was the reason nothing started. I tried to just delete this file (config.xml) (in the above Oracle forum thread they also suggest to delete the domain - but this was not an option for me as it wasn't an integrated server) - after trying to start the server manually again, WebLogic starter script politely asked me if I want it to create a new default config.xml, since the old one was not found - answering yes worked and I am back in business (i hope :P)

of course, i lost some (EDIT: not all) of the custom settings i did in WebLogic configuration since installing it - I lost the custm data sources, but users and user groups were retained. if only i had backed up this config.xml :( anyway.

(EDIT: probably backing up config.xml wouldn't make sense - anyway - i think it keeps the reference to data source for all the deployed applications - so - you don't have to recreate a data source - you just have to redeploy your application(s))